# Select two buttons which will lead to an "if statement" (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to get back into iOS programming, but it's been a while so I've kind of lost it.

I'm trying to make a simple single view game. I have four buttons. Button 1, button 2, button 3, and button 4.

**What I need to happen is:** When I press a button, the button gets selected, and then I want the user to be able to press any other button, which will then lead to an **if statement** that I'm gonna code later.

*Also,* I want the user to be able to unselect the previously selected button by just clicking it again. So that he or she can select another button of their choice, to start with.

I'd really appreciate this simple setup of code, since I have no clue how I'm gonna do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to change the state of the other buttons in the selector (IBAction) for the 1st button after it is pressed and control goes back to the user.

Whatever happens to the 3 button seems to imply that you just want them set or unset then evaluated at the same time - the more appropriate class to use is a UISwitch so you can set - unset them all at once without triggering an action. Of course you may use buttons if you wish but typically each button will trigger a selector instead of your code patiently waiting for the user to make up his mind in setting the options before your code starts again.

In case you forgot: 
  - (void)viewDidLoad {

```
[super viewDidLoad];
[Button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(Button1_pressed:)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[Button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(Button2_pressed:) 
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  Button2.enabled = NO;

 [Button3 addTarget:self action:@selector(Button3_pressed:)           
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   Button3.enabled = NO;

   ....  }

-(IBAction) Button1_pressed:(ID) sender {
   Button2.enabled = YES;
   Button3.enabled = YES;
   Button4.enabled = YES;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

the above functionality can be easily achieved by managing flag to know if button is already selected or not.

set `slected=1;` when user press the button,
selecting again will change flag to `selected=0` will help you to get selected status of button easily.

Comment: Why would you use `1` and `0`? Why not make it a `BOOL`?

Comment: 1 and 0 is just example, BOOL will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Take a BOOL variable isSelected.

```
isSelected = ! isSelected;
if(isSelected){
    button.enabled = NO;
 }
else{
    button.enabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: Eliminate the `if` statement. Just do `button.enabled = !isSelected;`.